# Is there any way force to pass an argument as reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

As the question above, I want to make the code below working.

Several types of string arguments should be passed to a function.

```cpp
    // declaration, maybe in .h file
    int matches(std::string& s1, std::string& s2, std::string& s3);

    inline int matches(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3) {
        return matches((std::string&) s1, (std::string&) s2, (std::string&) s3); // here i can't figure out
    }


    // implementation
    int matches(std::string& s1, std::string& s2, std::string& s3) {
        ...
    }

    int main() {
        std::string foo("foo"), bar("bar"), baz("baz");

        matches("foo",  "bar",   "baz" );
        matches( foo,    bar,    "baz" );
        matches( foo,   "bar",   "baz" );
        ...
        matches("foo",   bar,    "baz" );
        matches( foo,    bar,     baz  );

        return 0;
    }
```

I've googled minutes, but couldn't find solution.

Do I need to give up this problem?

Any suggestion or reply would be appreciated.

Comment: `std::string&&` — but this looks like an XY problem to me. What is it you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Dúthomhas `matches(T&)` is a function constantly called in a service process, and I want to minimize assign operator calls for string.

Comment: If you don't need to modify argument strings (e.g. only comparison), then you should change `std::string& s1` to `const std::string &s1`. `T &` is lvalue-reference (it must be a named variable), but `"foo"` is rvalue and can't be bound to lvalue-reference.

Comment: @RuslanTushov I want to pass strings to `inline matches(std::string...)` first, then to main function(but `matches( foo, bar, baz)` should directly go to main function). impossible?

Comment: @codingmonster You don't need `int matches(std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3)` if you change `int matches(std::string& s1, std::string& s2, std::string& s3)` to `int matches(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3);` (add `const` to argument types). I wrote why `matches("foo", "bar", "baz")` didn't compile in previous comment.

Comment: @RuslanTushov +1 Thank you very much, it's working. But I wonder `match(foo,bar,baz)` doesn't call `=`operator, does it? p.s.+1 above (literal doesn't match `std::string&&` as Duthomas mentioned.)

Comment: @RuslanTushov, I've just tested it and confirmed that it's a perfect solution for me. Please write an answer, I'll check solution for you. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@RuslanTushov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5059145/ruslan-tushov), I've found solution.

I post my own answer here for anyone with the same problem.

```cpp
    // implementation
    int matches(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2, const std::string& s3) {
        ...
    }

    int main() {
        std::string foo("foo"), bar("bar"), baz("baz");

        matches("foo",  "bar",   "baz" );
        matches( foo,    bar,    "baz" );
        matches( foo,   "bar",   "baz" );
        ...
        matches("foo",   bar,    "baz" );
        matches( foo,    bar,     baz  );

        return 0;
    }
```